# How can I reset a state without declare a initialState?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a state and I wan't to reset this state without necessity of create the same state twice

```
initialState: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        index: ''
      },
state: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        index: ''
      }
```

When I want to reset the state I do that

```
resetForm () {
      this.state = this.initialState
    }
```

How can I do that without a initialState declaration

Comment: This thread may be worth your time: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1118

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define an `initialState` object and then spread over it:

```
const initialState = {
  id: '',
  name: '',
  index: ''
}
...

state: {
  ...initialState
}

...

resetForm() {
  this.state = { ...initialState }
}
```